# Prevent to navigate back in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent navigate back (prevent backspace key and back button in browser) using JavaScript or jQuery. My language is coldfusion 8.

Comment: Not possible. You have to create your own browser. Try Adobe Air browsers

Comment: Good thing you don't want to block mouse gestures and the context menu too…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery code to prevent move back using backspace key. Add to script

```
$(document).unbind('keydown').bind('keydown', function (event) {
var doPrevent = false;
if (event.keyCode === 8) {
    var d = event.srcElement || event.target;
    if ((d.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT' && (d.type.toUpperCase() === 'TEXT' || d.type.toUpperCase() === 'PASSWORD')) 
         || d.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'TEXTAREA') {
        doPrevent = d.readOnly || d.disabled;
    }
    else {
        doPrevent = true;
    }
}

 if (doPrevent) {
    event.preventDefault();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do this in the code of all the pages you don't want the user to navigate back to:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
    window.history.forward();
    function prevent()
    {
     window.history.forward(); 
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="prevent();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) prevent();" onunload="">
    <!--content here-->
    </body>
    </html>
```